# View does not affect models changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an get action, which has a couple of parameters. In view I have a form, that fills after get action. Action creates an instance of model using received parameters, but if parameter has special value then action set to model some default values despite parameters. After that action return view with model. 
The problem is that after changing the model in View shows data of the parameters, and not from the modified model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because, by design, all HTML helpers first look at the ModelState when binding and after that in the model itself. So if you intend to modify some value that was part of the POST request you will need to remove it from ModelState first if you want this change to be reflected in the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    // We remove the Bar property that was part of the request because
    // we modify its value here
    ModelState.Remove("Bar");
    model.Bar = "Some modified value";

    return View(model);
}
```

This assumes that in the corresponding view you have an input field for it:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
```

Comment: Actually I'm using GET request, but your solution works very well. Thank you very much! Best regards.